# Can I set an app to run when the device is Idle on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I work as a software developer, but I am absolutely new to Apple in general. We have the following case in a project, and we have not been able to figure out a solution for it, I would really appreciate some advise to find a solution (or drop the case if not possible)

A (potential) customer with multiple retail stores is interested in having a very simple app to display some content (this could an image or html, nothing too complicated) and periodically update this content from a server (this requirement is important). So it is very simple case, to use the device screen as advertising space

But here is the catch, users should be able to go out of this app and check out the device's system and other apps, and then the content should come back on the foreground when the device is idle. So basically we need something like a screensaver app that fetches the content (images) from a server and keeps them updated.

We have been looking at the guided access mode, but we are not sure it fulfills the requirements, because of the following issues
- Allowing the user to check out the device system and other apps. As far as we understood guided access restricts the device to one app.
- Re-launch the app (or bring it to the foreground) when the device has been idle for a period of time.

Note that we should account for a variety of devices (iPhone and iPads) with different OS versions

I appreciate your help and ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not allow apps to run continuously in the background except for a small limited group of exceptions. (music playing apps, for example.)

It's possible to set up your app to pretend to be a music playing app, and stay running in the background, but that means you will not be allowed on the app store.

Your client may be able to use the enterprise program to create apps for use in their retail stores. Enterprise apps don't have to go through the app store approval process.

I did this for a client recently (for an enterprise app.) As I recall I would have the app request background processing as soon as it moved to the background, and when it was notified that it's background time was ending, I would play a short "silence" sound and request another block of background time. Unfortunately it was work for hire and the contract ended, so I did not retain the source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Duncan really appreciate it. Will have a looka enterprise apps